# Thread interrupt alternatives?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Building a Flashlight App with SOS mode. Has 3 buttons( On, Off and SOS). App works in normal On and Off mode but not in SOS mode.(SOS mode doesnt switch off)

```
//this method gets called when Off button is pressed
    private void turnOffFlash() {
            if (FlashOn) {
                if (myCamera == null || myParameters == null) {
                    return;
                }
                myParameters = myCamera.getParameters();
                myParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                myCamera.setParameters(myParameters);
                myCamera.stopPreview();
                try {
                    if (SOSon)
                        Flashthread.interrupt();
                    SOSon = false;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
                FlashOn = false;
                number_of_press=0;
            }
        }
```

and the `Flashthread`is used here

```
void onSOSPress() {
        if (number_of_press == 1) {
            try {
                SOSon = true;
                if (!Flashthread.isInterrupted()) {
                    if (SOSon) {
                        Flashthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                for (int i = 0; i < System.currentTimeMillis(); i++) {
                                    if (FlashOn) {
                                        myParameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                                        myCamera.setParameters(myParameters);
                                        FlashOn = false;
                                    } else {
                                        TurnOnFlash();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Flashthread.start();
                    }
                } else
                    Flashthread.resume();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `turnOffFlash` method,since I read that the Interrupt method doesn't really "interrupt"/kill the thread,what can I use instead of `Thread.Interrupt();` so that pressing the `Off` button stops the `SOS` mode?
I tried the `stop()` and `destroy()` but both crashed the app.

Comment: Why use such a convoluted system of starting and killing threads at all? What's wrong with using a `Handler` instead?

Comment: Will try out SOS mode using a 'Handler'. But in general, what would I need to do in this situation where Interrupt doesn't really do the task intended?

Comment: Also if possible could you please send a code sample of implementing this using a 'Handler' ? Thank You!

Comment: Anurah can u show ur Flashthread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should use is a `Handler` as suggested in the comments, but if you want to stick with this system, use a flag to tell your thread to stop:

```
boolean shouldStop = false;

...
while (!shouldStop){
  if(FlashOn){
    ...//do SOS stuff
  }
}

...
public void endSOS(){
  shouldStop = true;
}
```

Comment: Just a secondary question. Would this code run the SOS mode only once as any thread once stopped cannot be restarted?

Comment: Yeah, although you could modify it to allow restarting. However what I would do is just instantiate a new instance of whatever this class is and start that. Make sense?

Comment: Yes I did that but it crashes at this step  ' myCamera.setParameters(myParameters); '

Comment: Sorry for the trouble haha I fixed it with a small change. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `Thread#interrupt()` if you want to the force the Exception to be thrown.

```
boolean isClose = false;

while(!isClose){
  try {
      // Your code here
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     if(isClose){
        break;
     }
  }
}

public void killThread(){
  isClose = true;
  interrupt();
}
```

To implement the code.

```
 MyCustomThread t = new MyCustomThread(....);

 // Assuming that the thread is already running
 t.killThread();
```

This approach is often used in one of the popular libraries like `Volley` etc.