# Option like SOSModule didn't work

Tags: java, android, camera-flash

I am trying create option like SOS Module in my app, I create code to handle this:

```
class SOSModule {
private Camera camera;
private Camera.Parameters params;
private boolean isFlashOn;

void blink(final int delay, final int times) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                for (int i=0; i < times*2; i++) {
                    if (isFlashOn) {
                        turnOffFlash();
                    } else {
                        Camera.open();
                        turnOnFlash();
                    }
                    sleep(delay);
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
    }

}

void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;
    }
}
```

}

I also add all required permissions in manifest and of course I check uses permission on time.

But this no work. I just create other code but working like "one flash" without any cycle.

Can you guys help me?

Guys this is important for me, i cant do this becouse my Huawei p8 Lite and p9 Lite dont give any errors when this happend, its a Huawei software problem, with camera i need test it on psychical device, and its a big problem that i no have any logs from devices.

```
  public void flash_effect() throws InterruptedException
{
    cam = Camera.open();
    final Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
    p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);


    Thread a = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                cam.stopPreview();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
    a.start();
}}
```

This code worked, but flash is open for infinity without any blink effect
Any idea??

Comment: does it crash and throw an exception or it simply does not do anything on SOS button press?

Comment: Had a similar issue earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055659/thread-interrupt-alternatives

Comment: Nothing happend when i click the SOS button

Comment: Increase your sleep time from 50 to more value and see if it works

Comment: you can't see the log , maybe you can see the Toast , so you can use the Toast to show some infos as a tool....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your thread run is not get called

Try this

```
 void blink(final int delay, final int times) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                for (int i=0; i < times*2; i++) {
                    if (isFlashOn) {
                        turnOffFlash();
                    } else {
                        turnOnFlash();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

you can read more here

[Thread: Not calling run method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808895/thread-not-calling-run-method)

Answer (score 1):

You need a flag that tells your thread when to stop.

```
boolean shouldStop = false;

    while (!shouldStop){
      if(FlashOn){
        ...//do SOS stuff
      }
    }

    public void endSOS(){
      shouldStop = true;
    }
```

Comment: In the run function, yes.